# in javascript, image must change with var lvl, but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, image-management

I'm new in javascript and in web programming on the whole.
I'm trying to make script which will change image `pic0.png` depending on `var lvl`'s value.

This is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    var pic = "pic0.png";
</script>

<img id="myImg" src="pic0.png" width="107" height="98">
<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute of the image.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() 
{
    var lvl = 2;
    if (lvl = 1)
    {
        pic = "pic1.png";
    }
    else if (lvl = 2)
    {
        pic = "pic2.jpg";
    }
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = pic;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When `var lvl` equals to 2, picture must change to `pic2.jpg`, but there is problem - after I click button 'try it!', the picture changes to `pic1.png`, no matter if `var lvl` equals 2 or 1.

Comment: Check your Comparison operators..Must be `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the value instead of checking. You need to use the double equal operator:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var lvl = 2;
  if (lvl == 1)
  {
    pic = "pic1.png";
  }
  else if (lvl == 2)
  {
    pic = "pic2.jpg";
  }
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = pic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have forgotten about comparison operator.

Comment: @Hugo Please mark this as the correct answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`==` or `===` should be used when comparing. `=` is an assignment operator.

```
if (lvl == 1)
{
pic = "pic1.png";
}
else if (lvl == 2)
{
pic = "pic2.jpg";
}
```